# Relying on auto increment feature of MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I always have one "ID" field in my tables and do my work PHP side with those ID's.

Like;

```
id      Username
1       User1
2       User2
3       User3
```

PHP works like this;

```
show_member_details.php?memberID=3
```

The ID field is always set to auto increment.

Is it safe to rely on auto increment feature of MySQL on big projects/tables? Like a million of entries in a table?

Comment: Why would you feel this is unsafe?

Comment: I've read on an article where MySQL auto increment feature is sometimes unreliable on huge tables. (like a million entries) Can't find the link though.

Comment: What do you mean by unreliable?

Comment: Imagine you do this task on PHP side. There are 3 people in a table, but you deleted one, so the total is now 2. PHP itself would give a new registrant to have ID 3 by counting ID table. But, the ID 3 belongs to the account which you deleted. Therefore, it could have his comments saved somewhere. The new account would automatically get old account's comments attached. Things like that basically. Auto increment feature would give a new registrant 4 as ID, so it wouldn't effect the other tables. However, will it count successfully on huge tables, or after database restores?

Comment: the only way auto_increment is unreliable is if you choose a too-small integer type for your expected usage. e.g. look at twitter which used a signed 32bit int for the tweet ID - they ran out and had to rebuild using bigints.

Comment: @AnılÜnal: uh, auto_increment does NOT re-use deleted IDs. that's why it's reliable. once an id is used, even if the row is later thrown away (e.g. transaction rollback, delete, etc...), the id is **GONE**.

Comment: Well firstly, if a comment exists in the DB without the user existing, you do not have the correct foreign keys structure... Secondly, when assigning a new ID (from the DB side) it should not be reusing the same ID

Comment: So, it is perfectly safe to rely on auto increment for saving ID's on huge tables with millions of entries? I usually save ID column as INT(11). Doubt I'll ever need LONGINT. A million entries is the maximum amount my database will probably ever reach.

@astander; It doesn't really matter if the comments made by third account stays in comments table. Won't effect the application.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define it as AUTO INCREMENT.

You need to define your ID field as BIGINT whose range is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

FOR safely display in url you can encrypt it.

Comment: actully -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 (signed) or 0 to 18446744073709551615 (unsigned).

Comment: Carelessly utilizing `BIGINT` is a bad idea. It'll waste storage space and processing time and thus shouldn't be used unless it's truly needed.

Comment: @Dagon : i think we will not store our ID field in (-) sign. eg.. -1,-2 ..  Am i right ?

Comment: I wouldn't but its not an invalid approach. @Lusitanian, true but the difference would be minuscule